# Image format the same as /dev/fb0

Tags: linux, images, framebuffer

Is there an image format that is the same as `/dev/fb0`? So that `dd if=the_image of=/dev/fb0` would display the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it figured out... `sudo yum install fbida` or `sudo apt-get install fbi`.

```
fbi --help
  ....
  This program displays images using the Linux framebuffer device.
  Supported formats: PhotoCD, jpeg, ppm, gif, tiff, xwd, bmp, png.
  It tries to use ImageMagick's convert for unknown file formats.
  ....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert one image to adapt the format of /dev/fb0, try [this](https://github.com/zqb-all/convertfb)

Comment: This downvote is wrong. The answer is very useful.